# How to make double input writeable ko.computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to write a computed so I can choose between text input and text from a select drop down, but somewhere down the route I´m stuck.
I have an '' collecting my text string 
From a '' I can choose among 'Projects'. 
Then I have a checkbox which decides whether the text from the selected project should override my input-textstring.
If the  is empty. the selected project.title should set it.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: $root.toDo" placeholder="What to do?" /><br/><br/>

<select data-bind="options: $root.Projects, optionsCaption: '< choose project >', optionsText: 'title', value: $root.selected"></select><br/>
<input id="useProjectTitle" type="checkbox" value="toDoUseProjectTitle" data-bind="checked: $root.toDoUseProjectTitle" />
<label for="useProjectTitle">Use project title as action</label>

<div data-bind="with: $root.toDo">
    <label>I prefer:</label>
    <ul >
        <li >
            Project: <span data-bind="text: $root.toDoProjectAction"></span><br/> <!-- Project title--> 
            To do: <span data-bind="text: $root.toDo"></span>  <!-- toDo -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
Project = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.id;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
};

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Projects = ko.observableArray();

    // data
    self.Projects.push(new Project({
            id: 1, 
            title: 'Friday night live'
        }));
    self.Projects.push(new Project({
            id: 2, 
            title: 'Saturday morning gym'
        }));

    self.selected = ko.observable();
    self.toDoUseProjectTitle = ko.observable(false);

    self.toDoProjectAction = ko.computed(function () {
        var title; 
        var project = self.selected();
        if (project) {
            title = project.title();
        }
        return title;
    });

    self.toDo = ko.computed({
        read: function (value) {
            if (self.selected()) { // not 'undefined' or null
                if (self.toDoUseProjectTitle() || value === null) {
                    value = self.selected().title();
                }
            }
            return value;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            return value;
        },
        owner: self
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/srwr37k0/

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Is this what you are wanting? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srwr37k0/12/) I can add an answer if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. Unfortunately that´s not what I wanted. I´d messed up my fiddle with a test. The "toDo2" has nothing to do with it. I want the 'toDo'-observable to trigger the preview. 
If the checkbox is checked the  selected project.title should overwrite 'toDo'

If 'toDo' is blank, the selected project.title should overwrite 'toDo' even it the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: Fiddle cleaned up again now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your desired behavior, but I have modified your Fiddle to use an extra variable and to correct your writable computed. It could be rearranged to work without a writable, but I didn't. :)

```
self.handEntered = ko.observable('');
self.toDo = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var value = self.handEntered();
        if (self.selected()) { // not 'undefined' or null
            if (self.toDoUseProjectTitle() || value === null) {
               value = self.selected().title();
            }
        }
        return value;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        self.handEntered(value);
    },
    owner: self
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srwr37k0/14/

Comment: Great! Thanks, @Roy_J! Just by curiosity; how would you do it without a writable?

Comment: bind the textInput directly to handEntered. It really makes more sense that way: you have two inputs (each with its own variable) and one (read-only) computed that decides between them for its value.

Comment: And then put a "visible:!isSelected()" flag on the textInput:handEntered ?

Comment: So that the text input only shows up if you have no selection in the select list? That sounds reasonable.